# How to set the title which is multiple divs side by side in printing mode for datatables

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, datatables

How to set the `title` which is multiple divs side by side in printing mode for datatables.

```
 var table = $('#displayTable').DataTable({
                        "ordering": false,
                        data: parsedData.data,
                        responsive: false,
                        dom: 'Bfrtip',
                        buttons: [

                            {
                                extend: 'print',
                                title: $("#rep_header").html(),
                                footer: true,
                                customize: function (win) {
                                    $(win.document.body).find('thead').prepend('<div class="header-print">' + $('#dt-header').val() + '</div>');
                                    $(win.document.body).find('table')
                                        .addClass('table table-striped table-bordered')
                                        .css('direction', 'rtl');
                                    
                                    $(win.document.body).find('#rep_head_2_con').css('text-align', 'center');
                                    $(win.document.body).find('#rep_head_3_con').css('text-align', 'left');
                                    $(win.document.body).find('#rep_head_3_con').css('vertical-align', 'top');  
                               
                                }
                            },
```

---

HTML:

```
        <div id="rep_header">
            <div id="rep_head_1">
                <p id="rep_head_1_con">
                    AAA
                   <br />
                    BBB
                </p>
            </div>
            <div id="rep_head_2">
                <p id="rep_head_2_con">
                    AAA
                   <br />
                    BBB
                </p>
            </div>
            <div id="rep_head_3">
                <p id="rep_head_3_con">
                    AAA
                   <br />
                    BBB
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The text alignment goes well but the divs `(rep_head_1,rep_head_2,rep_head_3)` goes one under the other not beside each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to add `inline-block` to each of the three divs inside your `rep_header` div:

```
        <div id="rep_header">
            <div id="rep_head_1" style="display: inline-block;">
                <p id="rep_head_1_con">
                    AAA
                   <br />
                    BBB
                </p>
            </div>
            <div id="rep_head_2" style="display: inline-block;">
                <p id="rep_head_2_con">
                    CCC
                   <br />
                    DDD
                </p>
            </div>
            <div id="rep_head_3" style="display: inline-block;">
                <p id="rep_head_3_con">
                    EEE
                   <br />
                    FFF
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Now the data will be displayed as follows:

```
AAA  CCC  EEE
BBB  DDD  FFF
```

This will affect both the web page and the print page, of course.

If you only want to change the print page, then you can add the `style="display: inline-block;"` inside your DataTables `customize` function, in the same way that you are already adding `text-align` and other css styles.

You can also provide additional styling (e.g. padding, margins) to add more space between the divs, if needed.